# Where to Host Multiple PDF Files to Download on Request.

Tags: android, pdf, hosting

My app involves displaying pdf files.. including all pdf files can create a huge apk. The user will be provided with an option to select some files.On selecting a file download progress bar should be displayed and the file should be downloaded.
Does google play store provide space for hosting such files and download it on user request?Or should i use separate hosting?

Comment: [Take a look at this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/storing-your-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does google play store provide space for hosting such files and download it on user request?**

Ans: No, It only provide space to host your apk.

**should i use separate hosting?**

Ans: Yes, you can use any host or any cloud platform like google cloud platform to host your pdf and download it when required.

**Some other option to upload big apk file to playstore is:**

If your app needs more than 100MB of memory, you can use expansion files to store additional APK assets. You can store two expansion files per application. Each expansion file can be up to 2GB in size.

Check this link: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for hosting separate PDF files and and download one at a time then answer is no. Google play console dose not provide this service.

You do have an option of hosting a separate .obb file(zipped file)(You might know it already) containing all the files knows as Expansion file.

You can use google cloud, Amazon bucket.. any hosting service that fulfils your need.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need to do is Host your all the PDF files at some Server from where you can download them.

In-app just fetch the name and id of the PDF file and whenever User request to download it and start downloading it from server by using PDF URL.